# Is it possible to append values to a column if it is missing a value from a master column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare between different columns in an Excel sheet/csv.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xjSy.png)

For example, the master column has all the variables that I want to look at, but as you can see in the year 2015 and 2016, there are missing values when compared to the master column. Is it possible to write something in Python such that I can append all the missing variables of the master column into the 2015/2016 columns?

I have added the code to show the output in text form:

Input data:

```
     Master      2015    2016
0     apple     apple  banana
1    banana    cherry  cherry
2    cherry  elephant     NaN
3   digglet       NaN     NaN
4  elephant       NaN     NaN
```

code to create the above dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Master':['apple','banana','cherry','digglet','elephant'],
                   '2015':['apple','cherry','elephant',np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   '2016':['banana','cherry',np.NaN,np.NaN, np.NaN]})
print (df)
```

Thank you!

Comment: what should your final output look like? same as master column for 2015 & 2016? Also, what have you tried so far that you can share with us. Note: Stack Overflow is not a coding service platform.

Comment: Are you looking to create a duplicate column as master to replace 2015 and 2016? Without having clarity on this post, we are flagging it to close.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming I understand correctly what you want to do and your dataframe is called `df`, you can use `where` from `numpy` and do this:

```
import numpy as np

df['2015'] = np.where(df['2015'].isnull(),'df['Master'],'df['2015'])
df['2016'] = np.where(df['2016'].isnull(),'df['Master'],'df['2016'])
```

which uses `isnull()`, and fills the values of the columns 2015 and 2016 with the values from Master, when blank.

Using a `loop`:

```
cols_to_fill = ['2015','2016']
for col in df[cols_to_fill]:
    df[col] = np.where(df[col].isnull(),df['Master'],df[col])
```

which does the same as above.

Comment: This does not provide the desired result. The first code (for 2015) will skip `banana` and the second code (for 2016) will skip `apple`.  2015 will have 2 elephant and 2016 will have 2 cherry

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not fully answer your question but you can use `pd.DataFrame.update`:
(This also works with simple plain dicts)

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                       'B': [400, 500, 600]})
    
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],
                           'C': [7, 8, 9]})
    
    df.update(new_df)
```

df will be:

```
        A  B
        0  1  4
        1  2  5
        2  3  6
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP wanted?